# how to keep height of the table constant regardless of no of rows in it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-pdf

HERE IS THE CODE FROM MY table.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  table: {
    display: 'table',
    width: 'auto',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    textAlign: 'left',
    // minHeight: 500,
  },
  tableRow: {
    margin: 'auto',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // flexGrow: 0,
  },
  tableCol: {
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderRight: 1,
    borderBottom: 1,

    // borderWidth: 1,
    // borderLeftWidth: 0,
    // borderTopWidth: 0,
  },
  tableCell: {
    marginBottom: 5,
    fontSize: 9,
    paddingLeft: 3,
  },
})

const Table = ({ tableData }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.table}>
        <View style={{ ...styles.tableRow, backgroundColor: '#c0c0c0' }}>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>S.No</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '8%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>HSN</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>MFG</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '28%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Product Name</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Pack</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '8%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Batch No</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '6%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Expiry</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Qty</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '6%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Free</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '5%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Rate</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '5%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Amount</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>MRP</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '7%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>Disc%</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '7%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.tableCell}>GST%</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        {tableData.map((data, index) => (
          <View style={styles.tableRow} key={index}>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.sno}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '8%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.hsn}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.mfg}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '28%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.productName}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.pack}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '8%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.batchNo}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '6%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.expiry}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.qty}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '6%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.free}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '5%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.rate}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '5%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.amount}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '4%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.mrp}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '7%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.disc}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.tableCol, width: '7%' }}>
              <Text style={styles.tableCell}>{data.gst}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Table
```

app.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import Title from './components/Title'
import {
  PDFViewer,
  Page,
  Document,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
} from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import Table from './components/Table'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

const App = () => {
  const tableData = [
    {
      sno: 0,
      hsn: 30049061,
      mfg: 'MIC',
      productName: 'DOLO 650',
      pack: 15,
      batchNo: 'TESTNEW',
      expiry: '02/2025',
      qty: 1,
      free: '',
      rate: 24.0,
      amount: 24.0,
      mrp: 31.0,
      disc: 12,
      gst: 12,
    },
    {
      sno: 0,
      hsn: 30049061,
      mfg: 'MIC',
      productName: 'DOLO 650',
      pack: 15,
      batchNo: 'TESTNEW',
      expiry: '02/2025',
      qty: 1,
      free: '',
      rate: 24.0,
      amount: 24.0,
      mrp: 31.0,
      disc: 12,
      gst: 12,
    },
    {
      sno: 0,
      hsn: 30049061,
      mfg: 'MIC',
      productName: 'DOLO 650',
      pack: 15,
      batchNo: 'TESTNEW',
      expiry: '02/2025',
      qty: 1,
      free: '',
      rate: 24.0,
      amount: 24.0,
      mrp: 31.0,
      disc: 12,
      gst: 12,
    },
    {
      sno: 0,
      hsn: 30049061,
      mfg: 'MIC',
      productName: 'DOLO 650',
      pack: 15,
      batchNo: 'TESTNEW',
      expiry: '02/2025',
      qty: 1,
      free: '',
      rate: 24.0,
      amount: 24.0,
      mrp: 31.0,
      disc: 12,
      gst: 12,
    },
    {
      sno: 0,
      hsn: 30049061,
      mfg: 'MIC',
      productName: 'DOLO 650',
      pack: 15,
      batchNo: 'TESTNEW',
      expiry: '02/2025',
      qty: 1,
      free: '',
      rate: 24.0,
      amount: 24.0,
      mrp: 31.0,
      disc: 12,
      gst: 12,
    },
    {
      sno: 0,
      hsn: 30049061,
      mfg: 'MIC',
      productName: 'DOLO 650',
      pack: 15,
      batchNo: 'TESTNEW',
      expiry: '02/2025',
      qty: 1,
      free: '',
      rate: 24.0,
      amount: 24.0,
      mrp: 31.0,
      disc: 12,
      gst: 12,
    },
    {
      sno: 0,
      hsn: 30049061,
      mfg: 'MIC',
      productName: 'DOLO 650',
      pack: 15,
      batchNo: 'TESTNEW',
      expiry: '02/2025',
      qty: 1,
      free: '',
      rate: 24.0,
      amount: 24.0,
      mrp: 31.0,
      disc: 12,
      gst: 12,
    },

    // Add more data for Page  as needed
  ]

  const maxRowsPerPage = 10
  const pagesData = []

  for (let i = 0; i < tableData.length; i += maxRowsPerPage) {
    const pageData = tableData.slice(i, i + maxRowsPerPage)
    pagesData.push(pageData)
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    page: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    section: {
      marginTop: 20,
      marginBottom: 35,
      marginLeft: 20,
      marginRight: 20,
      // flexGrow: 1,
      border: 1,
    },
    pageNumbers: {
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 15,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: 10,
    },
  })

  return (
    <PDFViewer style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}>
      <Document>
        {pagesData.map((pageData, pageIndex) => (
          <Page
            orientation="landscape"
            size="A4"
            key={pageIndex}
            style={styles.page}
          >
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Title title={`Page ${pageIndex + 1}`} />
              <Table tableData={pageData} />
              <Footer />
            </View>
            <Text
              style={styles.pageNumbers}
              render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) =>
                `Page ${pageNumber} of ${totalPages}`
              }
              fixed
            />
          </Page>
        ))}
      </Document>
    </PDFViewer>
  )
}

export default App
```

when you look into my screenshot there are only 7 rows in it so it is adjusting the height of my table accordingly, but what i want is to have height of my table same even though i have only one row in it. I have tried to keep height: 600 but all my rows are trying to take 600

[image]